# How do I remove the whitespace on the right side of my webpage?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue regarding this strange whitespace that's appearing on the side of my webpage that's cause by these 2 sections.

I tried using overflow-x:hidden to solve the problem and this caused my navbar to get fixed to the top of the page without the style. Would very much appreciate some expert help on the problem. Thanks!

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,700');

#header {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 width: 100%;
} 

html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
 color: #222;
}

.container-fluid {
 padding: 0px;
}

.btn-primary {
 background-color: #ADE75F;
 border: 1px solid #ADE75F;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
 background-color: #71D002;
 border: 1px solid #71D002;
}

/****************************************************************************/
/***************************** Mission & Vision *****************************/
/****************************************************************************/

.mission-vision container-fluid {
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}

.mission-vision h3 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
 text-align: center;
}

.mission-vision p {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
 text-align-last: center;
}

.mission-vision .card {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.mission-vision .card-group a {
 text-decoration: none !important;
}

.mission-vision .card-title, .card-text {
 color: white;
}

.mission-vision hr.card-line {
 border-top: 4px solid;
 width: 120px;
 margin: 30px auto;
 color: #ADE75F;
}

.mission-vision .card-img-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.mission-vision .card-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black; /* fallback color */
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity:1;
}

.mission-vision .card:hover .card-img,
.mission-vision .card:focus .card-img {
 opacity:0.5;
}

/****************************************************************************/
/********************************** Footer **********************************/
/****************************************************************************/

footer {
 background-color: #3f3f3f;
 color: #d5d5d5;
 padding-top: 2rem;
}

hr.light {
 border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
 width: 80%;
 margin-top: .8rem;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

footer a {
 color: #d5d5d5;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: .2s all;
}

footer ul li {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

hr.light-100 {
 border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
 margin-top: .8rem;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

footer .padding {
 padding-bottom: .8rem;
}

.list-unstyled {
 list-style: none;
}

footer a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #71D002;
}

/*--- Bootstrap Padding Fix --*/
[class*="col-"] {
    padding: 1rem;
}

/*---Firefox Bug Fix --*/
.carousel-item {
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>CNY Gymnastics Centre</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<!---- Mission and Vision Card Group---->
<section class="mission-vision">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
    <div class="card-group">
     <div class="card">
      <a href="#">
          <img src="css/img/mission.jpg" class="card-img" alt="Mission">
          <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h3 class="card-title">Mission Statement</h3>
        <hr class="card-line">
             <p class="card-text">At CNY Gym Centre, our mission is to help each gymnast reach their full potential as a gymnast and as a person.  We treat each athlete as an individual doing our best to foster confidence and lasting self-esteem.  We strive to provide a safe and quality gymnastics program that will have an important and positive impact in your child’s future.  We are not only committed to helping each child become the best gymnast they can possible be, but also helping her/him become a happy, healthy and responsible person.  We believe that gymnastics is a vehicle in which we can teach skills that will last a lifetime, well beyond their gymnastics years.</p>
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
          </div>
      </a>
       </div>
     <div class="card">
      <a href="#">
          <img src="css/img/vision.jpg" class="card-img" alt="Vision">
          <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h3 class="card-title">Vision</h3>
        <hr class="card-line">
             <p class="card-text">With over 30 years of experience, we've become one of the top gymnastics clubs in New York state. We offer programs for children 6 months-18 years. Our programs range from Baby Gym and Parent and Tot to our birthday parties, summer camps, and our high performing teams. Whatever you sign up for, you can always expect that students will be taught in a fun, safe, and positive environment. Here, your child will gain new skills, learn life lessons, make great friends, and become a part of a close community like no other.</p>
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
          </div>
      </a>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section> 

<!--- Footer -->
<footer>
 <div class="container-fluid padding">
  <div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="css/img/Logo/logo-footer.png">
    <hr class="light">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
     <li>
      <a href="#">About Us</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Classes</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Schedule</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Birthdays</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Camps</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Team</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Upcoming Events</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <hr class="light">
    <h5>Shoppingtown</h5>
    <hr class="light">
    <p>3649 Erie Boulevard East DeWitt, NY 13214</p>
    <p>( 315 ) 437 - 4535</p>
    <p>Mon &amp; Fri: &nbsp; 1:00&nbsp;pm - 7:30&nbsp;pm</p>
    <p>Tue - Th: &nbsp; 10:00&nbsp;am - 7:30&nbsp;pm</p>
    <p>Sat: &nbsp; 9:00&nbsp;am - 4:30&nbsp;pm</p>
    <p>Sun: &nbsp; Closed</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <hr class="light">
    <h5>Great Northern</h5>
    <hr class="light">
    <p>4155 State Highway 31 Clay, NY 13041</p>
    <p>( 315 ) 622 - 4600</p>
    <p>Mon - Fri: &nbsp; 10:00&nbsp;am - 9:00&nbsp;pm</p>
    <p>Sat: &nbsp; 10:00&nbsp;am - 9:00&nbsp;pm</p>
    <p>Sun: &nbsp; 11:00&nbsp;am - 6:00&nbsp;pm</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12">
    <hr class="light-100">
    <h5>&copy; cnygymcentre.com</h5>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: You are going to need to provide a demo of your site to illustrate your problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem using .no-gutters on each of the rows. This removed the margin and padding that was causing the whitespace on the right side of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,700');

#header {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 width: 100%;
} 

html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
 color: #222;
}

.container-fluid {
 padding: 0px;
}

.btn-primary {
 background-color: #ADE75F;
 border: 1px solid #ADE75F;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
 background-color: #71D002;
 border: 1px solid #71D002;
}

/****************************************************************************/
/***************************** Mission & Vision *****************************/
/****************************************************************************/

.mission-vision container-fluid {
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}

.mission-vision h3 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
 text-align: center;
}

.mission-vision p {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
 text-align-last: center;
}

.mission-vision .card {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.mission-vision .card-group a {
 text-decoration: none !important;
}

.mission-vision .card-title, .card-text {
 color: white;
}

.mission-vision hr.card-line {
 border-top: 4px solid;
 width: 120px;
 margin: 30px auto;
 color: #ADE75F;
}

.mission-vision .card-img-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.mission-vision .card-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black; /* fallback color */
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity:1;
}

.mission-vision .card:hover .card-img,
.mission-vision .card:focus .card-img {
 opacity:0.5;
}

/****************************************************************************/
/********************************** Footer **********************************/
/****************************************************************************/

footer {
 background-color: #3f3f3f;
 color: #d5d5d5;
 padding-top: 2rem;
}

hr.light {
 border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
 width: 80%;
 margin-top: .8rem;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

footer a {
 color: #d5d5d5;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: .2s all;
}

footer ul li {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

hr.light-100 {
 border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
 margin-top: .8rem;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

footer .padding {
 padding-bottom: .8rem;
}

.list-unstyled {
 list-style: none;
}

footer a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #71D002;
}

/*--- Bootstrap Padding Fix --*/
[class*="col-"] {
    padding: 1rem;
}

/*---Firefox Bug Fix --*/
.carousel-item {
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>CNY Gymnastics Centre</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<!---- Mission and Vision Card Group---->
<section class="mission-vision">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
    <div class="card-group">
     <div class="card">
      <a href="#">
          <img src="css/img/mission.jpg" class="card-img" alt="Mission">
          <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h3 class="card-title">Mission Statement</h3>
        <hr class="card-line">
             <p class="card-text">At CNY Gym Centre, our mission is to help each gymnast reach their full potential as a gymnast and as a person.  We treat each athlete as an individual doing our best to foster confidence and lasting self-esteem.  We strive to provide a safe and quality gymnastics program that will have an important and positive impact in your child’s future.  We are not only committed to helping each child become the best gymnast they can possible be, but also helping her/him become a happy, healthy and responsible person.  We believe that gymnastics is a vehicle in which we can teach skills that will last a lifetime, well beyond their gymnastics years.</p>
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
          </div>
      </a>
       </div>
     <div class="card">
      <a href="#">
          <img src="css/img/vision.jpg" class="card-img" alt="Vision">
          <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h3 class="card-title">Vision</h3>
        <hr class="card-line">
             <p class="card-text">With over 30 years of experience, we've become one of the top gymnastics clubs in New York state. We offer programs for children 6 months-18 years. Our programs range from Baby Gym and Parent and Tot to our birthday parties, summer camps, and our high performing teams. Whatever you sign up for, you can always expect that students will be taught in a fun, safe, and positive environment. Here, your child will gain new skills, learn life lessons, make great friends, and become a part of a close community like no other.</p>
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
          </div>
      </a>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section> 

<!--- Footer -->
<footer>
 <div class="container-fluid padding">
  <div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="css/img/Logo/logo-footer.png">
    <hr class="light">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
     <li>
      <a href="#">About Us</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Classes</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Schedule</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Birthdays</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Camps</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Team</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Upcoming Events</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <hr class="light">
    <h5>Shoppingtown</h5>
    <hr class="light">
    <p>3649 Erie Boulevard East DeWitt, NY 13214</p>
    <p>( 315 ) 437 - 4535</p>
    <p>Mon &amp; Fri: &nbsp; 1:00&nbsp;pm - 7:30&nbsp;pm</p>
    <p>Tue - Th: &nbsp; 10:00&nbsp;am - 7:30&nbsp;pm</p>
    <p>Sat: &nbsp; 9:00&nbsp;am - 4:30&nbsp;pm</p>
    <p>Sun: &nbsp; Closed</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <hr class="light">
    <h5>Great Northern</h5>
    <hr class="light">
    <p>4155 State Highway 31 Clay, NY 13041</p>
    <p>( 315 ) 622 - 4600</p>
    <p>Mon - Fri: &nbsp; 10:00&nbsp;am - 9:00&nbsp;pm</p>
    <p>Sat: &nbsp; 10:00&nbsp;am - 9:00&nbsp;pm</p>
    <p>Sun: &nbsp; 11:00&nbsp;am - 6:00&nbsp;pm</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12">
    <hr class="light-100">
    <h5>&copy; cnygymcentre.com</h5>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</footer>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,700');


body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


#header {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 width: 100%;
} 

html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
 color: #222;
}

.container-fluid {
 padding: 0px;
}

.btn-primary {
 background-color: #ADE75F;
 border: 1px solid #ADE75F;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
 background-color: #71D002;
 border: 1px solid #71D002;
}

/****************************************************************************/
/***************************** Mission & Vision *****************************/
/****************************************************************************/

.mission-vision container-fluid {
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}

.mission-vision h3 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
 text-align: center;
}

.mission-vision p {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
 text-align-last: center;
}

.mission-vision .card {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.mission-vision .card-group a {
 text-decoration: none !important;
}

.mission-vision .card-title, .card-text {
 color: white;
}

.mission-vision hr.card-line {
 border-top: 4px solid;
 width: 120px;
 margin: 30px auto;
 color: #ADE75F;
}

.mission-vision .card-img-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.mission-vision .card-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black; /* fallback color */
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity:1;
}

.mission-vision .card:hover .card-img,
.mission-vision .card:focus .card-img {
 opacity:0.5;
}

/****************************************************************************/
/********************************** Footer **********************************/
/****************************************************************************/

footer {
 background-color: #3f3f3f;
 color: #d5d5d5;
 padding-top: 2rem;
}

hr.light {
 border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
 width: 80%;
 margin-top: .8rem;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

footer a {
 color: #d5d5d5;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: .2s all;
}

footer ul li {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

hr.light-100 {
 border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
 margin-top: .8rem;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

footer .padding {
 padding-bottom: .8rem;
}

.list-unstyled {
 list-style: none;
}

footer a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #71D002;
}

/*--- Bootstrap Padding Fix --*/
[class*="col-"] {
    padding: 1rem;
}

/*---Firefox Bug Fix --*/
.carousel-item {
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>CNY Gymnastics Centre</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<!---- Mission and Vision Card Group---->
<section class="mission-vision">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
    <div class="card-group">
     <div class="card">
      <a href="#">
          <img src="css/img/mission.jpg" class="card-img" alt="Mission">
          <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h3 class="card-title">Mission Statement</h3>
        <hr class="card-line">
             <p class="card-text">At CNY Gym Centre, our mission is to help each gymnast reach their full potential as a gymnast and as a person.  We treat each athlete as an individual doing our best to foster confidence and lasting self-esteem.  We strive to provide a safe and quality gymnastics program that will have an important and positive impact in your child’s future.  We are not only committed to helping each child become the best gymnast they can possible be, but also helping her/him become a happy, healthy and responsible person.  We believe that gymnastics is a vehicle in which we can teach skills that will last a lifetime, well beyond their gymnastics years.</p>
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
          </div>
      </a>
       </div>
     <div class="card">
      <a href="#">
          <img src="css/img/vision.jpg" class="card-img" alt="Vision">
          <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h3 class="card-title">Vision</h3>
        <hr class="card-line">
             <p class="card-text">With over 30 years of experience, we've become one of the top gymnastics clubs in New York state. We offer programs for children 6 months-18 years. Our programs range from Baby Gym and Parent and Tot to our birthday parties, summer camps, and our high performing teams. Whatever you sign up for, you can always expect that students will be taught in a fun, safe, and positive environment. Here, your child will gain new skills, learn life lessons, make great friends, and become a part of a close community like no other.</p>
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
          </div>
      </a>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section> 

<!--- Footer -->
<footer>
 <div class="container-fluid padding">
  <div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="css/img/Logo/logo-footer.png">
    <hr class="light">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
     <li>
      <a href="#">About Us</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Classes</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Schedule</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Birthdays</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Camps</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Team</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Upcoming Events</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <hr class="light">
    <h5>Shoppingtown</h5>
    <hr class="light">
    <p>3649 Erie Boulevard East DeWitt, NY 13214</p>
    <p>( 315 ) 437 - 4535</p>
    <p>Mon &amp; Fri: &nbsp; 1:00&nbsp;pm - 7:30&nbsp;pm</p>
    <p>Tue - Th: &nbsp; 10:00&nbsp;am - 7:30&nbsp;pm</p>
    <p>Sat: &nbsp; 9:00&nbsp;am - 4:30&nbsp;pm</p>
    <p>Sun: &nbsp; Closed</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <hr class="light">
    <h5>Great Northern</h5>
    <hr class="light">
    <p>4155 State Highway 31 Clay, NY 13041</p>
    <p>( 315 ) 622 - 4600</p>
    <p>Mon - Fri: &nbsp; 10:00&nbsp;am - 9:00&nbsp;pm</p>
    <p>Sat: &nbsp; 10:00&nbsp;am - 9:00&nbsp;pm</p>
    <p>Sun: &nbsp; 11:00&nbsp;am - 6:00&nbsp;pm</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12">
    <hr class="light-100">
    <h5>&copy; cnygymcentre.com</h5>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: This is often a problem, The golden rule in my book is to include the following code at the top of my main CSS file: 
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
} // See if that works. It seems to have worked in the sni[[et

Comment: The problem seems to still persist, sir. :(

Comment: Apologies that didn't work. As @Lee Taylor said, it would be very useful if you provide a demo of your site so that we can see the problem that you are experiencing. Can you post a link to it?

Comment: Of course. Really appreciate the help! https://github.com/SenpaiCAL/cny_gym_centre_website

Comment: Excellent! I was just about to post a link and say that I could not see or replicate the white space you were talking about. I'm glad you got it sorted though. :)